# Predicate doesn't work at CoreData - Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

**Im trying to load Name with index 1, but it's not working (CollectionView is empty).**

**CoreData**:

[image]

**LoadData:**

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }

let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let fetchRequestTag = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Tag")
let PreValue = 1
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "index == %i", PreValue)
fetchRequestTag.predicate = predicate

do {
   tagItems = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequestTag)
} catch let error as NSError {
   print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}

TagCollectionView.reloadData()
TagCollectionView.selectItem(at: NSIndexPath(item: 0, section: 0) as IndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: [])

for data in tagItems {
   print("\(data.value(forKey: "name") as! String as Any), \(NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data.value(forKeyPath: "index") as! Data) as! Int)")
}
```

Comment: If `index` is an integer then why is it set as `Transformable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute type and the predicate type don't match.

`Transformable` as type for an *index* is nonsensical anyway. Set the attribute type to `Int32`, or if there are only `0` and `1` indexes even to `Bool`.